# GridSearchCV Error on param_grid With RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator RandomForestRegressor().
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

This is the error i get while using GridSearchCV on a RandomForestRegressor model.
Here's the code

```
%%time 
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

rf_grid= {"estimator__n_estimators ": np.arange(10,100,10),
      "estimator__max_depth ": [None,3,5,10],
      "estimator__min_sample_split": np.arange(2,20,2),
      "estimator__min_sample_leaf" : np.arange(1,20,2),
      "estimator__max_features ": [0.5,1,'sqrt','auto'],
      "estimator__max_samples" : [10000]
}
rfr_2=RandomForestRegressor()

rs_model= RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=rfr_2,
                        param_distributions=rf_grid,
                        n_iter=100,
                        cv=5,
                        verbose= True)

rs_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Turns out I'm supposed to use single quotes ' ' instead of double "  " .

```
 %%time 
 from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

 rf_grid= {'n_estimators': np.arange(10,100,10),
      'max_depth': [None,3,5,10],
      'min_samples_split': np.arange(2,20,2),
      'min_samples_leaf' : np.arange(1,20,2),
      'max_features': [0.5,1,'sqrt','auto'],
      'max_samples' : [100]
  }

  rs_model= RandomizedSearchCV(rfr,
                        param_distributions=rf_grid,
                        n_iter=100,
                        cv=5,
                        verbose= True)
  rs_model.get_params()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message:

> ValueError: Invalid parameter estimator for estimator RandomForestRegressor().
> Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

you can see that you erroneously specified the parameters in the `rf_grid`.

Use:

```
rf_grid= {"n_estimators": np.arange(10,100,10),
      "max_depth": [None,3,5,10],
      "min_samples_split": np.arange(2,20,2),
      "min_samples_leaf" : np.arange(1,20,2),
      "max_features": [0.5,1,'sqrt','auto'],
      "max_samples" : [10000]
}
```

as suggested from:

```
rfr_2.get_params().keys()
```

> dict_keys(['bootstrap', 'ccp_alpha', 'criterion', 'max_depth',
> 'max_features', 'max_leaf_nodes', 'max_samples',
> 'min_impurity_decrease', 'min_impurity_split', 'min_samples_leaf',
> 'min_samples_split', 'min_weight_fraction_leaf', 'n_estimators',
> 'n_jobs', 'oob_score', 'random_state', 'verbose', 'warm_start'])

Comment: This is what i wrote first time , but it showed "n_estimators" is an invalid param for RandomForestRegressor() .

Comment: What version of scikit are you using? With up-to-date [version](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html), `n_estimators` is a valid parameter for that estimator.

Comment: It is upto date , i've posted the solution down below if you're interested , it's a silly one

Comment: You have accepted an answer posted after mine with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to see how you should name your parameters inside your dictionary, you can print them beforehand like this:

```
print(rfr_2.get_params())
```

After you've printed all the parameters, now you can choose which ones you are going to pass into the grid dictionary

What you should do is get rid of the "estimator__", that you put in front of every parameter.

Also, once you do that, you will encounter another error. Namely, parameter max_samples can take a value between 1 and 232, the value that you've put (10000) is too high.
Below is the block of the code that is modified, and should work!

```
rf_grid= {"n_estimators": np.arange(10,100,10),
  "max_depth": [None,3,5,10],
  "min_samples_split": np.arange(2,20,2),
  "min_samples_leaf" : np.arange(1,20,2),
  "max_features": [0.5,1,'sqrt','auto'],
  "max_samples" : [100]
```

Comment: Tried these out before posting ,  `estimator.get_params().keys()` suggested i add estimator name in the beginning .

Comment: The first time you tried, it's possible it threw you an error because you put "min_sample_split" and "min_sample_leaf" instead of "min_samples_split" and "min_samples_leaf". Please try with the code I provided, since I recreated the whole environment and it worked

Comment: Thanks for taking the time , 
Yes i did face an error before and now that i went back to it , it was due to using double quotes instead of single ones . i've posted the solution down below btw